# Why does df.limit keep changing in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm creating a data sample from some dataframe `df` with

```
rdd = df.limit(10000).rdd
```

This operation takes quite some time (why actually? can it not short-cut after 10000 rows?), so I assume I have a new RDD now.

However, when I now work on `rdd`, it is different rows every time I access it. As if it resamples over again. Caching the RDD helps a bit, but surely that's not save?

What is the reason behind it?

Update: Here is a reproduction on Spark 1.5.2

```
from operator import add
from pyspark.sql import Row
rdd=sc.parallelize([Row(i=i) for i in range(1000000)],100)
rdd1=rdd.toDF().limit(1000).rdd
for _ in range(3):
    print(rdd1.map(lambda row:row.i).reduce(add))
```

The output is

```
499500
19955500
49651500
```

I'm surprised that `.rdd` doesn't fix the data.

EDIT:
To show that it get's more tricky than the re-execution issue, here is a single action which produces incorrect results on Spark 2.0.0.2.5.0

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
rdd=sc.parallelize([Row(i=i) for i in range(1000000)],200)
rdd1=rdd.toDF().limit(12345).rdd
rdd2=rdd1.map(lambda x:(x,x))
rdd2.join(rdd2).count()
# result is 10240 despite doing a self-join
```

Basically, whenever you use `limit` your results might be potentially wrong. I don't mean "just one of many samples", but really incorrect (since in the case the result should always be 12345).

Comment: How do you create `df`?

Comment: `df` is read directly from an HDFS parquet file.

Answer (score 12):

Because Spark is distributed, in general it's not safe to assume deterministic results. Your example is taking the "first" 10,000 rows of a DataFrame. Here, there's ambiguity (and hence non-determinism) in what "first" means. That will depend on the internals of Spark. For example, it could be the first partition that responds to the driver. That partition could change with networking, data locality, etc.

Even once you cache the data, I still wouldn't rely on getting the same data back every time, though I certainly would expect it to be more consistent than reading from disk.

Comment: Sure, between different runs I will get different results the first time I read it. But here I assign it to `rdd1` and apparently this get recalculated. This basically implies that everything can be potential wrong once you use `limit` somewhere.

Comment: You're right that `rdd1` will be recalculated if it's not cached. My point is that your only guarantee with the `limit(N)` function is that you will get at most that `N` elements from the RDD. There are no guarantees about _which_ elements you'll get or, as you're noticing, that those elements will be the same. You can't base the logic of your program on a guarantee of consistency. If you really need to get the _same_ elements every time, you'll have to use something else, like a filter or a global sort, which do have consistency guarantees.

Comment: That's clear. But here is something: I could make a single call which will give incorrect results. I just have to use rdd1 in two parts of thr DAG and make a final call in the end. Maybe should update the question to show the implications.

Comment: Can you be more specific by "make a single call"? You can define the RDD once (e.g. `rdd = df.limit(10000).rdd`). But spark evaluates lazily, so it's not until you call something like `rdd.first()` that the computation takes place. At that point, spark more or less interprets this as "Give me the first element out of 10000 random rows from `df`". When you call `rdd.first()` later, you kick off another computation, which can give different results than the first time.

Comment: Have a look at the question edit. I call join only once and it gives wrong results from the start. I know what you explain. The catch is rather that limit is so lazy that is get evaluated in the same DAG twice in different ways.

Comment: I think there is still a misunderstanding. Don't think of an RDD as ever actually being materialized. That is, don't think of `rdd1` as 12,345 integers. Think of it as a description of a computation that guarantees a list of at most 12,345 integers, but there is no _specificity of what those integers are_. It doesn't matter when or how or how often you reference the RDD, it's just a description of a computation. When you reference `rdd1` multiple times, you're asking for the output of the computation twice with no guarantees of consistency.

Comment: Well what if you do a `.orderBy()` followed by a `.limit()`? Then surely, the results should be deterministic/the same

Answer (score 8):

Spark is lazy, so each [action](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-actions.html) you take recalculates the data returned by limit(). If the underlying data is split across multiple partitions, then every time you evaluate it, limit might be pulling from a different partition (i.e. if your data is stored across 10 Parquet files, the first limit call might pull from file 1, the second from file 7, and so on).

Answer (score 7):

From the [Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-limit.html):

> The `LIMIT` clause is used to constrain the number of rows returned by the `SELECT` statement. In general, this clause is used in conjunction with `ORDER BY` to ensure that the results are deterministic.

So you need to sort the rows beforehand if you want the call to `.limit()` to be deterministic. But there is a catch! If you sort by a column that doesn't have unique values for every row, the so called "tied" rows (rows with same sorting key value) will not be deterministically ordered, thus the `.limit()` might still be nondeterministic.

You have two options to work around this:

- Make sure you include the a unique row id in the sorting call.
  For example `df.orderBy('someCol', 'rowId').limit(n)`.
  You can define the `rowId` like so:
  `df = df.withColumn('rowId', func.monotonically_increasing_id())`
- If you only need deterministic result in the single run, you could simply cache the results of limit `df.limit(n).cache()` so that at least the results from that limit do not change due to the consecutive action calls that would otherwise recompute the results of `limit` and mess up the results.