# Dataframe and corresponding RDD return different rows (PySpark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I am facing a weird behavior where the dataframe and the downstream list and map generated from its RDD equivalent seem to be returning different rows. What could be possibly going wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Below is a snippet of the code along with the output:

1. `samples` is a dataframe with 10 rows and three columns (resulting from sampling 10 random rows from another larger dataframe `subset_df`). Later, I concatenate the first two columns.
2. Detailed code is given below. I dump out the dataframe, key-value map of counts generated, and finally a processed version of the RDD based on the dataframe. Ideally, they are all expected to contain the same set of urls. But they are different. I understand if the order is different (because doing `.collect()` on a rdd could possibly produce a different ordering), but some of the rows returned are completely different. For eg: the third output seems to produce several urls that never exist in the dataframe from which this rdd is generated. This seems really weird!

FULL CODE:

```
samples = subset_df.select("post_visid_low", "post_visid_high", "post_page_url").where( 
        subset_df["post_page_url"] != "").sample(False, 0.1, seed=0).limit(num_samples) 

tmp = samples.select(func.concat(func.col("post_visid_low"), func.lit("-"), func.col("post_visid_high")).alias( 
        'user_id'), "post_page_url") 
print("tmp show:") 
tmp.show(10, False)

# term freq computation 
vocab = tmp.select("post_page_url").groupBy("post_page_url").count().rdd.collectAsMap() 
for k,v in vocab.items(): 
    print(k,v)


# group by user_ids 
user_id_urls = tmp.rdd.reduceByKey( 
    lambda x,y: x + "," + y) 
num_users = user_id_urls.count() 
print("user_id_urls:") 
user_id_urls.collect()
```

OUTPUT:

tmp dataframe show():

```
+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
|user_id                                |post_page_url                                                                               | 
+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
|6917530152391623611-2707424459370863148|http://www.backcountry.com/Store/catalog/shopAllBrands.jsp                                  | 
|6917530609264617841-2788188800375174579|http://www.backcountry.com/Store/catalog/shopAllBrands.jsp                                  | 
|6917530818644021208-2821777435347267515|http://www.backcountry.com                                                                  | 
|6917530818644021208-2821777435347267515|http://www.backcountry.com/rc/mens-sale-snow-outerwear-jackets                              | 
|6917530818644021208-2821777435347267515|http://www.backcountry.com/rc/mens-sale-snow-outerwear-jackets                              | 
|6917530818644021208-2821777435347267515|http://www.backcountry.com/dakine-washburn-jacket-mens                                      | 
|1657310128-1262694438                  |http://www.backcountry.com/santa-cruz-bicycles-5010-2.0-carbon-r-complete-mountain-bike-2016| 
|4611687717086954899-2907911088913069555|http://www.backcountry.com/ugg-bixbee-bootie-toddler-infant-boys                            | 
|2023386797-562458996                   |http://www.backcountry.com                                                                  | 
|6917530783747871522-2923626095076314968|http://www.backcountry.com/pikolinos-verona-boot-womens                                     | 
+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

vocab map:

```
http://www.backcountry.com/boys-jackets 2 
http://www.backcountry.com/dakine-titan-mittens 1 
https://www.backcountry.com/Store/account/account.jsp 1 
http://www.backcountry.com/ski-clothing 1 
http://www.backcountry.com/the-north-face-runners-1-etip-glove 1 
http://www.backcountry.com/patagonia 1 
http://www.backcountry.com/burton-boys-clothing 1 
http://www.backcountry.com/mens-shorts 1 
https://www.backcountry.com/Store/account/login.jsp 1
```

user_id_urls rdd:

```
[(u'4611687717086954899-2907911088913069555', 
  u'http://www.backcountry.com/ugg-bixbee-bootie-toddler-infant-boys'), 
 (u'2023386797-562458996', u'http://www.backcountry.com'), 
 (u'6917530783747871522-2923626095076314968', 
  u'http://www.backcountry.com/pikolinos-verona-boot-womens'), 
 (u'6917530818644021208-2821777435347267515', 
  u'http://www.backcountry.com,http://www.backcountry.com/rc/mens-sale-snow-outerwear-jackets,http://www.backcountry.com/rc/mens-sale-snow-outerwear-jackets,http://www.backcountry.com/dakine-washburn-jacket-mens'), 
 (u'6917530152391623611-2707424459370863148', 
  u'http://www.backcountry.com/Store/catalog/shopAllBrands.jsp'), 
 (u'6917530609264617841-2788188800375174579', 
  u'http://www.backcountry.com/Store/catalog/shopAllBrands.jsp'), 
 (u'1657310128-1262694438', 
  u'http://www.backcountry.com/santa-cruz-bicycles-5010-2.0-carbon-r-complete-mountain-bike-2016')]
```

Comment: Not sure, if this is a similar problem as that mentioned in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37147032/why-does-df-limit-keep-changing-in-pyspark

Comment: what is suppose to be equal to what ? you seem to be doing a lot a stuff to a lot of data. Your reducebykey seems questionable by the way, although I have no idea what you are expecting from it.