# How to slice a pyspark dataframe in two row-wise

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am working in Databricks.

I have a dataframe which contains 500 rows, I would like to create two dataframes on containing 100 rows and the other containing the remaining 400 rows.

```
+--------------------+----------+
|              userid| eventdate|
+--------------------+----------+
|00518b128fc9459d9...|2017-10-09|
|00976c0b7f2c4c2ca...|2017-12-16|
|00a60fb81aa74f35a...|2017-12-04|
|00f9f7234e2c4bf78...|2017-05-09|
|0146fe6ad7a243c3b...|2017-11-21|
|016567f169c145ddb...|2017-10-16|
|01ccd278777946cb8...|2017-07-05|
```

I have tried the below but I receive an error

```
df1 = df[:99]
df2 = df[100:499]


TypeError: unexpected item type: <type 'slice'>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Initially I misunderstood and thought you wanted to slice the columns. If you want to select a subset of rows, one method is to create an index column using [`monotonically_increasing_id()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id). From the docs:

> The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and
>   unique, but not consecutive.

You can use this ID to sort the dataframe and subset it using `limit()` to ensure you get exactly the rows you want.

For example:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
import string

# create a dummy df with 500 rows and 2 columns
N = 500
numbers = [i%26 for i in range(N)]
letters = [string.ascii_uppercase[n] for n in numbers]

df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(
    zip(numbers, letters),
    ('numbers', 'letters')
)

# add an index column
df = df.withColumn('index', f.monotonically_increasing_id())

# sort ascending and take first 100 rows for df1
df1 = df.sort('index').limit(100)

# sort descending and take 400 rows for df2
df2 = df.sort('index', ascending=False).limit(400)
```

Just to verify that this did what you wanted:

```python
df1.count()
#100
df2.count()
#400
```

Also we can verify that the index column doesn't overlap:

```python
df1.select(f.min('index').alias('min'), f.max('index').alias('max')).show()
#+---+---+
#|min|max|
#+---+---+
#|  0| 99|
#+---+---+

df2.select(f.min('index').alias('min'), f.max('index').alias('max')).show()
#+---+----------+
#|min|       max|
#+---+----------+
#|100|8589934841|
#+---+----------+
```

Comment: use monotonically_increasing_id() can add monotonically increasing id to the table BUT it is not consecutive. so if you use limit(100), you wont' get 100 rows exactly

Comment: @Gavin you will get exactly 100 rows because `limit(n)` will return exactly `n` rows (assuming there's that many in the table, if there are not it will return all of the rows.). This only relies on the `monotonically_increasing_id()` to sort the table.

Comment: got it. but I cannot take the 200 to 300 rows using the index created by monotonically_increasing_id. right?

Comment: @Gavin That is correct, you can not. But as I explained in [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52792762/is-there-a-way-to-slice-dataframe-based-on-index-in-pyspark/52819758#52819758), relying on the order of the data is not recommended. In this example, the OP had a DataFrame with 500 rows- this technique likely does not generalize well for larger data.

Answer (score 13):

Spark dataframes cannot be indexed like you write. You could use head method to Create to take the n top rows. This will return a list of Row() objects and not a dataframe. So you can convert them back to dataframe and use subtract from the original dataframe to take the rest of the rows.

```
#Take the 100 top rows convert them to dataframe 
#Also you need to provide the schema also to avoid errors
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.head(100), df.schema)

#Take the rest of the rows
df2 = df.subtract(df1)
```

You can use also SparkSession instead of spark sqlContext if you work on spark 2.0+. Also if you are not interested in taking the first 100 rows and you want a random split you can use [randomSplit](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.randomSplit) like this:

```
df1,df2 = df.randomSplit([0.20, 0.80],seed=1234)
```

Answer (score 5):

If I don't mind having same rows in both dataframe's then I can use `sample`.  For e.g. I have a dataframe with 354 rows.

```
>>> df.count()
354

>>> df.sample(False,0.5,0).count() //approx. 50%
179

>>> df.sample(False,0.1,0).count() //approx. 10%
34
```

Alternatively, If I want to strictly split without duplicates being present, I could do

```
df1 = df.limit(100)     //100 rows
df2 = df.subtract(df1)  //Remaining rows
```

Comment: Using limit() is not straight forward due to lazy evaluation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37147032/why-does-df-limit-keep-changing-in-pyspark

Answer (score 3):

Try by this way :

```
df1_list = df.collect()[:99] #this will return list    
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df1) #convert it to spark dataframe
```

similarly for this as well:

```
df2_list = df.collect()[100:499]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In both solutions, I believe we need to change `df1` to `df1_list`, and change `df2` to `df2_list` in the second sentences.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to slice a data frame by row:

```
def slice_df(df,start,end):
    return spark.createDataFrame(df.limit(end).tail(end - start))
```

Answer (score -2):

Providing a much less complicated solution here more similar to what was requested:

(Works in Spark 2.4 +)

```
# Starting
print('Starting row count:',df.count())
print('Starting column count:',len(df.columns))

# Slice rows
df2 = df.limit(3)
print('Sliced row count:',df2.count())

# Slice columns
cols_list = df.columns[0:1]
df3 = df.select(cols_list)
print('Sliced column count:',len(df3.columns))
```