# Split Spark dataframe by row index

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to split a data-frame in row-wise order. If there are `100` rows, then desired split into 4 equal data-frames should have indices `0-24`, `25-49`, `50-74`, and `75-99`, respectively.

The only pre-defined function available is `randomSplit`. But `randomSplit` randomizes the data before splitting.
Another way I think of is to find the count of data using `count` reduction operation and then keep extracting the data using  `take` but it is very expensive.
Is there any other way to achieve the above while maintaining the same order?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48884960/how-to-slice-a-pyspark-dataframe-in-two-row-wise

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`monotonically_increasing_id`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id) to get the row number (if you don't already have it) and then [`ntile`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.ntile) over a row number window to split into however many partitions you want:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id, ntile

values = [(str(i),) for i in range(100)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(values, ('value',))

def split_by_row_index(df, num_partitions=4):
    # Let's assume you don't have a row_id column that has the row order
    t = df.withColumn('_row_id', monotonically_increasing_id())
    # Using ntile() because monotonically_increasing_id is discontinuous across partitions
    t = t.withColumn('_partition', ntile(num_partitions).over(Window.orderBy(t._row_id))) 
    return [t.filter(t._partition == i+1).drop('_row_id', '_partition') for i in range(partitions)]

[i.collect() for i in split_by_row_index(df)]
```

Comment: How do we implement the same for larger df?