# How to convert spark dataframe to python dataframe using a loop

Tags: python

I have created a spark dataframe which has 500k rows. If i convert it to python dataframe using `pandas_df = spark_df.toPandas()`, it takes a lot of time and disconnects. How can i create a loop which pulls up 100k rows from spark dataframe and puts it to python data frame and than iterate 5 times to create 5 df with 100k rows each?

Comment: What is your end goal? You can try exporting the dataframe into csv and import it back to pandas in chunks

Comment: or you can try this to split the data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48884960/how-to-slice-a-pyspark-dataframe-in-two-row-wise